# Copying the value of a pointer to another new pointer in Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, att

**Update:** I'm allowed to use strcpy in my code.

I'm trying to write an implementation of strdup in x86 assembly (att syntax), converting the code in C to code in Assembly.

Code in C:

```
char* func( int x, char* name){

    namestr = (char *) malloc( strlen(name) + 1 );
    strdup( namestr, name );
    free( name ); //Just showing what I plan to do later.

    return namestr;

}
```

Code in Assembly:

```
;basic start, char* I'm trying to copy is at 12(%ebp)
new_string: 
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    subl    $20, %esp
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, %edi
    movl    (%ecx), %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)

;get the length of the string + 1, allocate space for it
.STR_ALLOCATE: 
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    $-1, %ecx
    repnz   scasb
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    notl    %eax
    subl    $1, %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    malloc
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)

;copy value of of the char* back to %eax, save it to the stack, pass the address back
.STR_DUP: 
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
    leal    -12(%ebp), %eax

.END:
    popl    %edi
    leave
    ret
```

When I run the code, I only get a part of the char* back.
Example: Passing in "Stack Overflow" gets me "Stac@@#$$".
I guess I'm doing something wrong with the movl, not really sure what.

p/s: I'm pretty sure that my strlen works.

Part 2:
Would the code I wrote pass back a pointer to the caller? As in the ability to free whatever space I allocated later.

Comment: Because you get 4 characters right, I suspect that you're copying a pointer- (word-) sized region instead of the whole string, i. e. at some place you're making the pointer vs. array confusion (except that this is more harmful here than in C).

Comment: I guess your prototype  is like:

mystrcpy(char * src, char** dest) because of the movl  (%ecx),%ecx 
since that is not entirely the same as strcpy, maybe you should write out C code first, and add it to your question

Comment: You don't need to allocate any memory for `strcpy()` or `strlen()`. You stop reading/writing after the byte with value 0.

Comment: @H2CO3 yea, I'm pretty sure you're right but I can't see it myself.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I've added the code in C.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, even if I need a pointer that points to the char*? I believe I do if I need a pointer.

Comment: A pointer is only 4 bytes. Don't you have a spare register to hold it? If you don't, don't you have the stack to store it there? Surely, it won't overflow from just 4 extra bytes, will it?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Ok, I guess what I'm doing is more like strdup cause I'll be destroying the original char*, I can't just point to the original char*. I need to copy the value of the char* then return a pointer to the new char*. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I see. You should've clarified it from the beginning, it's more clear from your C code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit rusty assembler skills it would look like this:

```
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    subl    $20, %esp
    movl    12(%ebp), %edi
;get the length of the string + 1, allocate space for it
.STR_ALLOCATE: 
; next is dangerous. -1 is like scan "forever". You might want to set a proper upper bound here, like in "n" string variants.
    movl    $-1, %ecx
    repnz   scasb
    notl    %ecx
;    subl    $1, %ecx
;    addl    $1, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)
    pushl   %ecx
    call    malloc
    add     $4,%esp
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)   
    movl    -8(%ebp),%ecx
    movl    %eax, %edi
    movl    12(%ebp).%esi
    rep     movsb
    movl    -12(%ebp),%eax
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edi
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Well The code works, but if I attempt to free the original char* after freeing the new char*, I get an error saying that it is already freed.

Comment: And it frees fine without calling the routine? Try to print the pointer values before and after the routine. I don't know what your exact target and ABI is, I just copied the style of the original, and saved all extra regs